# Moving a single float to a xmm register

Tags: c++, gcc, x86, sse, simd

I want to multiply the data stored in one xmm register with a single float value and save the result in a xmm register.
I made a little graphic to explain it a bit better.

[image]

As you see I got a xmm0 register with my data in it. For example it contains:

xmm0 = |4.0|2.5|3.5|2.0|

Each floating point is stored in 4 bytes. My xmm0 register is 128 bits, 16 bytes long.

That works pretty good. Now I want to store 0.5 in another xmm register, e.g. xmm1, and multiply this register with the xmm0 register so that each value stored in xmm0 is multiplied with 0.5.

I have absolutely no idea how to store 0.5 in an XMM register. 
Any suggestions?

Btw: It's Inline Assembler in C++.

```
void filter(image* src_image, image* dst_image)
{
    float* src = src_image->data;
    float* dst = dst_image->data;

    __asm__ __volatile__ (              
        "movaps (%%esi), %%xmm0\n"      
        // Multiply %xmm0 with a float, e.g. 0.5
        "movaps %%xmm0, (%%edi)\n" 

        :
        : "S"(src), "D"(dst) :  
    );
}
```

This is the quiet simple version of the thing i want to do. I got some image data stored in a float array. The pointer to these arrays are passed to assembly. movaps takes the first 4 float values of the array, stores these 16 bytes in the xmm0 register. After this xmm0 should be multiplied with e.g. 0.5. Than the "new" values shall be stored in the array from edi.

Comment: It's better to use intrinsics nowadays. That way your code is compiler independent and you get automatic register allocation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As people noted in comments, for this sort of very simple operation, it's essentially always better to use intrinsics:

```
void filter(image* src_image, image* dst_image)
{
    const __m128 data = _mm_load_ps(src_image->data);
    const __m128 scaled = _mm_mul_ps(data, _mm_set1_ps(0.5f));
    _mm_store_ps(dst_image->data, scaled);
}
```

You should only resort to an inline ASM if the compiler is generating bad code (and only after filing a bug with the compiler vendor).

If you really want to stay in assembly, there are *many* ways to accomplish this task.  You could define a scale vector outside of the ASM block:

```
    const __m128 half = _mm_set1_ps(0.5f);
```

and then use it inside the ASM just like you use other operands.

You can do it without any loads, if you really want to:

```
    "mov    $0x3f000000, %%eax\n"  // encoding of 0.5
    "movd   %%eax,       %%xmm1\n" // move to xmm1
    "shufps $0, %%xmm1,  %%xmm1\n" // splat across all lanes of xmm1
```

Those are just two approaches.  There are lots of other ways.  You might spend some quality time with the Intel Instruction Set Reference.

Comment: +1 MOVD with an immediate value is much better than my version, which can only load from memory. Didn't think about using integer operations.

Comment: @ChristianRau: I don't think I'd say it's "much better"; that's going to depend on the surrounding context.  They're just different approaches.

Comment: I think it might be better for a constant, since it comes directly from the instruction cache and you don't have to fetch it from static memory. But you're right in that it depends and I'm not that much of a machine-expert, anyway.

Comment: @Copa: I happen to just know this value; I write a lot of low-level FP code.  A IEEE-754 single-precision number has an 8-bit exponent field and a 23-bit significand field.  The bias of the exponent field is 127.  So `1.0f = 2^0` is `127 + 0 << 23`, or `0x3f800000`; `0.5f = 2^-1` is `127 - 1 << 23`, which is `0x3f000000`.  Mere mortals may prefer to use http://babbage.cs.qc.edu/IEEE-754/ =P

Comment: @Christian: Loading an xmm register from a general purpose register may incur a penalty which is much bigger than the L1 cache latency, depending on the exact hardware. Additionally, any latency may be hidden by reordering.

Comment: @drhirsch: `movd` has been single-cycle on every µarch since Core.  I don't think there's a lot of high-performance code targeting Netburst at this point.  That said, your point about reordering is spot-on, and is more or less what I was getting at.

Comment: I was more referring to the data bypass delays present even in the Core i (Nehalem) architecture, which isn't that old. In Agner Fogs microarchitecture pdf, which I am sure you know of, it's listed as 1 additional cycle (under Execution ports), and of course it's one instruction more (mov immediate+movd vs. mov mem,xmm), which may clog up the instruction decoders. Sometimes I really do count each cycle at some spots, and I found that even on a modern architecture a _mov mem,xmm_ may be preferable (in other cases not :-)). But you are of course right, it always depends on the surr. context.

Comment: @drhirsch: There are precisely three scenarios that I am aware of in which conjuring an FP value in this fashion is a net win: (1) if you are completely *latency* bound (due to a dependency chain so long that the reorder buffer fills up and doesn't buy you anything) -- even with the Core i* bypass delay, the latency is less (2) if you're on 32-bit and need to load one or two constants, this saves giving up a register for a PIC base address (and saves two instructions to generate said address) (3) if your working set precisely fills L1 D$, and this prevents a miss.  All are corner cases.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're using intrinsics: `__m128 halfx4 = _mm_set1_ps(0.5f);`

**Edit:**

You're much better off using intrinsics:

```
__m128 x = _mm_mul_ps(_mm_load_ps(src), halfx4);
_mm_store_ps(dst, x);
```

If the `src` and `dst` float data is not 16-byte aligned, you need: `_mm_loadu_ps` and `_mm_storeu_ps` - which are slower.

Comment: Can I use this in inline assembler?

Comment: You could pass it as an operand. What compiler are you using?

Comment: I am using gcc for linux. What do you mean with "pass it as an operand"?

Comment: You need to show the inline assembly block - in particular, it's inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the MOVSS instruction (which loads a single precision float from memory into the lowest 4 bytes of an SSE register), followed by a shuffle to fill the other 3 floats with this value:

```
movss  (whatever), %%xmm1
shufps %%xmm1, %%xmm1, $0
```

That's also how the `_mm_set1_ps` intrinsic might probably do it. Then you can just multiply these SSE values or do whatever you want:

```
mulps %%xmm1, %%xmm0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using c++ with gcc and have EasySSE your code can be as follows

```
void filter(float* src_image, float* dst_image){
    *(PackedFloat128*)dst_image =  Packefloat128(0.5) * (src_image+0);
}
```

This is assuming the given pointers are 16byte aligned.
You can check the assy code to verify the variables are properly mapped to vector registers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct img {
    float *data;
} image_t;

image_t *src_image;
image_t *dst_image;
void filter(image_t*, image_t*);

int main()
{
    image_t src, dst;
    src.data = malloc(64);
    dst.data = malloc(64);
    src_image=&src;
    dst_image=&dst;

    *src.data = 42.0;
    filter(src_image, dst_image);

    printf("%f\n", *dst.data);
    free(src.data);
    free(dst.data);
    return 0;
}

void filter(image_t* src_image, image_t* dst_image)
{
    float* src = src_image->data;
    float* dst = dst_image->data;

    __asm__ __volatile__ (              
        "movd   %%esi, %%xmm0;"
        "movd   %%xmm0, %%edi;"
        : "=D" (*dst)
        : "S" (*src)
    );
}
```